# UICollectionView F# Call method in init

Tags: f#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, initialization, uicollectionviewcell

```
 [<Register ("ChatViewCell")>]
type ChatViewCell (handle: IntPtr) as this = 
    inherit UICollectionViewCell (handle)


    [<DefaultValue>] static val mutable private id : NSString

    static member init = 
        printfn "Initializing ChatViewCell."
        ChatViewCell.id <- new NSString("ChatCell")


    override this.ReuseIdentifier = ChatViewCell.id

    let mutable profileImageView = new UIImageView()
    let mutable nameLabel = new UILabel()
    let mutable messageLabel = new UILabel()
    let mutable timeofMessageLabel = new UILabel()
    let mutable dividerLineView = new UIView()
    let mutable countLabel = new UILabel()

    let setupView() = 
        profileImageView.Frame <- CGRect(50.0, 0.0, 200.0, 100.0)
        profileImageView.ContentMode <- UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.Layer.CornerRadius <- Conversions.nfloat(30)
```

I have the following `UICollectionViewCell` and I want to call the `setupView` method when the cell is initialised. However, the `setupView` method doesn't seem to be available within `init`. I tried moving it above `init`, however, this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setupView` is defined as an instance function because it doesn't not have the `static` modifier. It must be an instance function (or an instance method) because it accesses `profileImageView` which is an instance field.

The static member `init` cannot call an instance function because there is no way to explicitly pass an instance to an instance function (you can only explicitly pass an instance to a method).

If you want to do some initialization on construction of your `ChatViewCell` you can simply put your initialization statements in the body of the class. When you do this you need to use the `do` keyword which is normally implicit.

e.g.

```
type ChatViewCell (handle: IntPtr) as this = 
    inherit UICollectionViewCell (handle)

    let mutable profileImageView = new UIImageView()

    do profileImageView.Frame <- CGRect(50.0, 0.0, 200.0, 100.0)
    do profileImageView.ContentMode <- UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    do profileImageView.Layer.CornerRadius <- Conversions.nfloat(30)
```

Useful references:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/let-bindings-in-classes